# Node.js library for generating indexed PNGs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, png

**Does anyone know of a node.js module for creating *indexed* PNGs?**

I've looked through [this list](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-graphics) of node graphics modules, and some of them allow png creation, but none seem to allow you to specify an index/pallete scheme.

Just some extra info:  I have a 2d Array representing pixels, each referring to an index of a 1d palette array.  From this I would like to generate a valid indexed png file (1 channel, with 4 bits per channel).

Comment: Worst case scenario, you can roll your own. I [did this a while back](https://github.com/bitsofpancake/usain-png/blob/master/usain-png.js) as a web worker, and the spec is very straightforward to follow, but it's pretty slow.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [png-stream](https://github.com/devongovett/png-stream) could be worth a look. According to them:

> You can also write data in the indexed color space by first quantizing it using the neuquant module.

Also, depending on what you're intending to do, another (cumbersome) possibility would be to use [sng](http://sng.sourceforge.net/sng.html) to convert PNG files to and from a textual representation.

Another option would be [JS-PNG](http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/utilities/js_png/index.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Node-canvas version 2.0 and later support creating indexed PNGs. I put two examples in the repo:

- [indexed-png-alpha.js](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/blob/master/examples/indexed-png-alpha.js) uses high-level functions like `fillRect()` with the alpha channel.
- [indexed-png-image-data.js](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/blob/master/examples/indexed-png-image-data.js) operates on image data directly and sounds more fitting to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

[pngparse](https://github.com/ironwallaby/pngparse) will allow you to index, but I'm not sure about palette support.

Comment: As I understand it, that will only allow reading of png files though? Unless I missunderstand something?

Comment: yeah, you're right. only read not create indexed PNGs. sorry, i misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this, which allows you to use imagemagick via Node:
https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick

Comment: Seems more like a wrapper around the Imagemagick CLI tools. Could be useful for making conversions and adjustments to existing images, but not so much for more direct image manipulation.